# Google map is not loaded when open Browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have integrate a Google map in my website but map is not load in my website.But when I open inspect element map will work when I close inspect element map will disappear automatically.I don't know why its going like this,Please let me know what the problem. Here is my map code

Thanks in Advance

```
<div id="mapCanvas" style="width:100%; height:400px"></div> 
<input type="text" title="Latitude" id="latt_val">
<input type="text" title="Longitude" id="long_val">
```

```html
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
  document.getElementById("latt_val").value = latLng.lat();
  document.getElementById("long_val").value = latLng.lng();
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(15.486432009100538, 73.82759375);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
  
  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);
  
  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
 google.maps.event.trigger(window,'resize',{}); 
}
 
// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening it with different browsers?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE]

Hey, I'm still really curious what's going on here. Do you happen to have an AdBlocker enabled on your browser that might prevent the map from loading? Have you checked if this works in multiple browsers?

I made a codepen of our problem: http://codepen.io/trevorwhealy/pen/obRQdW. 
And your map is working perfectly fine. If, on-load of this pen, you still do not see something, then I think we can safely say this is a browser issue.

[OLD POST]

Try putting your code:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(window,'resize',{}); // or trigger(map
```

after

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
     geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
```

but still within your initialize function.